# Beginner Scala SBT query

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to modify closure compiler option based on the instructions at https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/193-javascript-require-support-in-non-minimized-files.

I need to add a resolver as well.

```
val defaultOptions = new CompilerOptions()
defaultOptions.closurePass = true
CompilationLevel.WHITESPACE_ONLY.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(defaultOptions)
defaultOptions.setProcessCommonJSModules(true)
val root = new java.io.File(".")
defaultOptions.setCommonJSModulePathPrefix(root.getCanonicalPath + "/app/assets/javascript/")
defaultOptions.setPrettyPrint(true)

def optClosureValues = Option(System.getProperty("closureoff")).filter(_ != "").map {
dev =>
  println("using alternative closure compiler")
  closureCompilerSettings(defaultOptions)
}.getOrElse(Seq.empty)


val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
optClosureValues:_*,
resolvers += ("Morphia" at "http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/")
)
```

This gives an error

```
Build.scala:35: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
[error] (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
[error]     optClosureValues:_*,
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
```

Whats the correct syntax here?

Comment: Also if I use just one of the 2 settings things work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably write like:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
  optClosureValues ++
  Seq(resolvers += ("Morphia" at "http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/")): _*
)
```

I confirmed the above working on my machine using the latest 2.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: @SauravShah Are you using play 2.1-SNAPSHOT?